# Using nuget packages in a script file

Tags: f#

I installed `FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator` in my library.  I added a reference to the install in the project.  Then, I added a reference to `FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator` in the module,

```
open FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator
```

The library compiles without error.

I then attempted to load the module in the script file included in the same library, but the module fails to load and complains that there is no definition for "Evaluator" as used in the module.

Also, when I run the code in FS interactive, the compiler does not recognize "Evaluator". There must be a `load` command I need to run, but `load "FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator"` does not work.

I assume I have to somehow load the nuget package in the script file.  However, I have no idea how to do that.  How do I get the script file to recognize `FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For F# interactive mode you can use the following snippet:

```
#I @".\my_lib_path"
#r "MyLib.dll"
open MyLib
```

where `#I` - lib path, `#r` - adding a reference to a lib,